# Same GPU, different manufacturer

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I have an NVidia 1080 ti and would like to add a second.  It looks like the only thing on the NVidia site is the Founder's Edition - and they're unavailable.  So my question is:

Would a 1080 ti made by, say, EVGA give the same results as my current card if they were used together on the same render?  I understand that they'll certainly work with Blender but my concern is for the quality of the render.

I've seen tons of SO questions regarding whether multiple cards will *work* but I'm curious to know if there are any significant differences under the hood which would yield a poorer render than going with two identical cards.

Using Blender 2.79 + Cycles

**Regarding "Marked as duplicate" designation:**  This question refers specifically to the *results* obtained from the use of different cards.  Other questions, such as the one linked in the duplicate notice, simply address the *support* of multiple cards.

Comment: I don't think you would have any issues mixing the same kind of processor in GPUs from different manufacturers. I've done renders mixing different brands and sometimes even different architectures (fermi and kepler) with no problems, other than one card being faster than other...

Comment: The model numbers refer to reference specs for a gpu, different manufacturers have same specs for same model numbers, ram, and cooling may change but the cuda cores in the gpu match. They all use the same nvidia drivers and should function the same. I expect mixing nvidia and amd gpus could fail but using all nvidia gpus should be good - regardless of having same manufacturer and/or model number.

Comment: @cegaton/@sambler - Ok, thanks.  My main concern was that two adjacent tiles rendered on the two different cards would look just slightly different or that the noise would be computed differently and would leave a visible seam.  Your responses have cleared this up, though.  If you'd like to leave an answer, I'll be glad to mark as such.